# Android - Rendering a widget after an event has been triggered

Tags: java, android

In android, how does one go about rendering a widget after an event has occurred. In this case, the event could be a radio button being pressed. After the render button is pressed, another widget (such as an textview or editbox) is rendered on the screen.

The widget that is dependent on the event, is currently written in the android layout xml file. Code looks like this:

```
        case R.id.radio_buttonID:
            if(Checked) {

                EditText  Enter_Info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_boxID);
                TextView  Display_Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sign_ID);
                percentSign.setText(R.string.Word);
            }
            break;
```

The above is part of a switch statement which is located in a function that handles the radio buttons. What is the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to show one view at run time ? when clicking the radio button

Comment: Do you want the radio button to disappear after being checked, then a textview will appear instead? Or after checking the radioButton, a textView appears beside/on top of it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by one view at run time. But any way, I want to render only one widget or view after the radio button has been pressed.

Comment: @sept, no I do not want the radio button to disappear. But if you know how to do that as well, then I would appreciate you sharing. The radio button appears below the radio button.

Comment: @Czar so basically, you just want a TextView to appear beside the radiobutton after being checked?

Comment: Yes, I want the TextView to appear beside the radio button

Comment: @Czar posted an answer. Hope it helps you in some way. :)

Comment: @sept Thanks you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample code will give you an idea of what you are planning to acheive. You can modify it to suit your need.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText Enter_Info;
private RadioButton radioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Enter_Info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_boxID);
    Enter_Info.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    radioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button);
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Enter_Info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            }else{
                Enter_Info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. If it has help you, you can mark it or upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Gonna go on ahead and post the code I did also, following the same onClick code pattern you are using, if ever someone is having a hard time understanding the ***setOnCheckedChangeListener*** pattern.

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvSample;
    private RadioButton rbSample;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        tvSample = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_sample);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.rb_sample:
                rbSample = (RadioButton) findViewById(v.getId());
                if (rbSample.isChecked()) {
                    tvSample.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Sample Radio Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sample"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can just replace the View (TextView/EditText) that you want to appear beside the RadioButton in the xml layout, just set the VISIBILITY to GONE first, then dynamically set it to VISIBLE in the code if it is checked. If you want the RadioButton to disappear after being checked, just set the VISIBILITY to GONE dyanmically. For more info regarding View elements, you can go to the Official Android Developers Site -- [View | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)